# SenchaTouch 2.3: Panel can't be scrolled

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I've got a strange problem with a panel in a hbox layout in SenchaTouch 2.3. The view extends Ext.Container. Here's the config:

```
config: {
    layout: "hbox",
    style: "padding-bottom: 20px;",
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            id: "stmc_info_buttons",
            cls: ["stmc_info_buttons", "shadow"],
            width: 350,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: "list",
                grouped: false,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                indexBar: false,
                cls: "stmc_info",
                id: "stmc_info_btn_entries",
                variableHeights: false,
                itemHeight: 35,
                store: {
                    id: "stmc_info_store",
                    model: "Stbg.model.Info",
                    proxy: {
                        type: "ajax",
                        url: "resources/json/info.json",
                        reader: {
                            type: "json",
                            rootProperty: "info"
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true
                },
                itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<tpl switch="typ">',
                    '<tpl case="rubrik">',
                    '<div class="contact2 {csscls}">{titel}</div>',
                    '<tpl default>',
                    '<div class="contact2 stmc_info_entry">{titel}</div>',
                    '</tpl>'
                )
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            layout: 'fit',
            flex: 1,
            id: "stmc_info_text",
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'vertical',
                directionLock: true
            },
            cls: ["stmc_info_text", "shadow"]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I tap an entry on the left, the panel on the right shows the corresponding content. Everything works fine. If the content is "longer" than the viewport it should be scrollable. But if I try to scroll the panel to the bottom and release my finger from the tablet, the view "jumps" back to the top. So I can't reach the bottom of the content. Where is the error?

The method to change the panel data does the following:

```
loadText: function (loadUrl, target) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: loadUrl,
        success: function (response, opts) {
            var panel = Ext.getCmp(target);
            if (panel != null) {
                panel.setHtml(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        failure: function (response, opts) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Additional info: The content being loaded is pure HTML. The problem only appears on Android Tablet. When I test the app in Chrome, the scrolling works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a height defined on your parent panel (with the hbox layout)... A height is necessary and needs to come from somewhere. I have run into a bug in 2.2.1 where after I've opened a floating panel on top of another I had scrolling issues... the new window was a card layout with 2 lists in it, the first list did not scroll and the second did. Needless to say, it was extremely frustrating so I wrote code to update the scroller's maxPosition myself. You can adapt the below code to your needs if you cannot figure out the issue.

```
//get the list / scroller instances
var list = window.down('list[listName=workorders-list]'),
    scroller = list.container.getScrollable().getScroller();

//each line item is set to be 47px tall, so we'll calculate the
//maxHeight based on records.length * 47 - container height
var maxHeight = parseInt(records.length,10) * 47 - parseInt(scroller._containerSize.y,10);

//if maxHeight is less than 0 adjust it to 0
if (maxHeight < 0) {
    maxHeight = 0;
}

scroller.maxPosition.y = maxHeight;
```